# marklogic MLCP output_uri_replace fail

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I'm trying to use a regular expression with -output_uri_replace, and it is failing.

Here is my options file:

```
import
-host
localhost
-port
8877
-username
xxxx
-password
xxxx
-input_file_path 
to-import
-output_uri_replace
^.*(/[^/]+/),$1
```

I consistently get this error:

```
$ import
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid option argument for output_uri_replace :^.*(/[^/]+/),$1
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.Command.applyCommonOutputConfigOptions(Command.java:2422)
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.Command$1.applyConfigOptions(Command.java:470)
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.Command$1.createJob(Command.java:370)
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runCommand(ContentPump.java:238)
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.main(ContentPump.java:74)
```

which is obviously not very helpful. I don't know why it doesn't report the error from the regex engine, which is capable of giving useful messages.

I tried with and without quotes. No difference.

Just to prove it works, here is what happens in Groovy (which uses the same regex engine as Java)

[image]

This is exactly the result I want. And by the way, wouldn't this be a common case? You have a bunch of stuff in the directory immediately below and you want to lop off everything but that?

Couldn't there be a working example in the documentation?

And why the @#$% doesn't this work in MLCP when it's clearly a valid regex?

Comment: I don't think it's the regex or the replacement. I'm seeing the same issue with just `foo,bar`.  It looks like it requires single quotes surrounding the replacement https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-contentpump/blob/25d395a1247b86ca5fd3f273b64430cba09242e7/src/main/java/com/marklogic/contentpump/Command.java#L2420 however, if I use `'foo','bar'` then I see it showing `invalid option argument for output_uri_replace :foo',bar` so I suspect something is wrong with quote stripping and requirements to have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with your regex.

It is just that the `-options_file` options have an odd requirement/expectation (maybe a bug) that the entire option value be wrapped in double quotes, and also that the replacement value be wrapped in single quotes.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_42798

> The -output_uri_replace option accepts a comma delimited list of regular expression and replacement string pairs. The string portion must be enclosed in single quotes:

I don't think that is very clear that the double quotes wrapping the option are required, and the error doesn't help you understand that.

I noticed that in the source code where that exception is thrown [it is looking for single quotes wrapping the replacements value](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-contentpump/blob/25d395a1247b86ca5fd3f273b64430cba09242e7/src/main/java/com/marklogic/contentpump/Command.java#L2417)

```
// Replacement string is expected to be in ''
for (int i = 0; i < replace.length - 1; i++) {
   String replacement = replace[++i].trim();
   if (!replacement.startsWith("'") || 
       !replacement.endsWith("'")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Invalid option argument for "
                + OUTPUT_URI_REPLACE + " :" + uriReplace);
    }
}
```

So, I tried wrapping the replacement value in quotes: `^.*(/[^/]+/),$1`
But then it complained about a malformed option, and I see it was making calls to `OptionsFileUtil.removeQuoteCharactersIfNecessary()`
So, then I tried wrapping both values in single quotes: `'^.*(/[^/]+/)','$1'`
But then it complained about invalid argument and the quotes were goofy:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Invalid option argument for output_uri_replace :^.*(/[^/]+/)','$1
```

I also verified this with simple strings `foo,bar` and saw same results.

If you wrap the entire value in double quotes and wrap the replacement value in single quotes:

```
-output_uri_replace
"^.*(/[^/]+/),'$1'"
```

then I was able to get it to execute without error.

I was also able to pass the `-output_uri_replace` via commandline, and it works (as long as you wrap the replacement value with single quotes):

```
mlcp.bat -options_file options.txt -output_uri_replace "^.*(/[^/]+/),'$1'"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I hope this can at least be documented, and ideally the behavior improved.

Comment: It helps to have customers voice their issues and pain points. I'd advise to open a Support ticket or create a GitHub issue: https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-contentpump/issues/new

Comment: Personally, I'd rather see the implementation improve, rather than document the requirement for double quotes wrapping the value (feels like a bug to me)